# What are the movies that Rocky owns, as inferred by the semantic web owl model?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I'm trying to understand the semantic web, and know a little about rdf, rdfs, and owl. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the following image is an owl diagram that shows the relationship between some properties, classes and objects. I'm having a little trouble understanding what the owl:oneof function does.

[image: This is an owl diagram]

From what I can see, because we have the triples

```
:JamesDeanMovie owl:allValuesFrom :ownsMovie all JamesDeanMovie.
:ownsMovie owl:onProperty :ownsMovie all JamesDeanMovie.
:JamesDeanMovie a owl:Class;
owl:oneof [EastofEden, Giant, Rebel].
```

we can infer that Rocky owns all movies because we have the owl:AllValuesFrom function. How can I write that in turtle format? or am I going about this wrong.

```
:Rocky a owl:Class
owl:oneof [EastofEden, Giant, Rebel].
```

Thanks

Comment: `:JamesDeanMovie owl:allValuesFrom :ownsMovie all JamesDeanMovie.` is for sure **not** a triple nor any other valid RDF syntax.

Comment: by the way, the "all" in `owl:allValuesFrom` means not "all" in what you might think. It's more an *"**only** elements of type ..."* - the important thing here is that OWL is not meant to model constraint but more restrictions on what will be inferred. E.g., `C EquivalentTo p only B` means that for all `p(x,y)` with `x` being an instance of `C` will infer that `y` belongs to class `B`.